# Making Custom SeekBar of color based on current theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-seekbar

I'm trying to make a custom `SeekBar` of `height="1dp"` & `width="match_parent"` and any color based on the *current selected theme*.

I've across [this great tutorial](http://javandroidevelop.blogspot.in/2012/09/cool-seekbar-custom-made-by-me.html?showComment=1393669049121) to do it. But it uses already prepared images.

Instead of images, I just want to use 1dp line of dynamic color.

In **styled_seekbar_progress.xml**, I wrote (this is the xml that uses `layerlist` to tell which drawable to use in `progress` & `SecondaryProgress`):

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_seekbar_played_1dp">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_seekbar_unplayed_1dp">
</item>
```

**drawable/img_seekbar_played_1dp.xml:
(?seekbar_line_played_color - color based on current theme)**

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.5dp"
    android:background="?seekbar_line_played_color"
/>
```

**img_seekbar_unplayed_1dp:**

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.5dp"
    android:background="?seekbar_line_unplayed_color"
/>
```

Project does not show any compile time error, but at run time it shows:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/styled_seekbar_progress.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020002
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag View
at.android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
```

I believe, I cant use  (in-place of Image) in `android:drawable="@drawable/img_seekbar_played_1dp"`. Android is expecting an image.

So how can I use my `<view>` to form a seekbar?

Thank You

Comment: what color do you want to use?

Comment: the color should be dynamic and decided on runtime based on current themes. But for simplicity just for now assume a single color say blue.

Comment: so use shape drawable, you can specify its solid color

Comment: @pskink but how to define 2 colors(for progress & secondary progress). I tried layer-list with 2 shape elements, but it is taking only one color, & not taking secondary color. Will highly appreciate if you can provide as an **answer**

Comment: see the default xml file http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/progress_horizontal.xml , the most important is "clip" tag